# How to display loader initially and then display text after loading ends based upon condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I want to display a loader initially and after a certain time when the loader is turned off manually based upon the condition I want to either fun a function or display a heading 1.

I want that when initially when the page loads, the loader should be displayed but after a certain time it turns off maybe with the help of setTimeout, and if the length of the array (videoIds) is 0 I want to display the heading "Enter at least one video in the collection first" otherwise if the length is not zero then run fetchFunc() and display result and thus render  component.

I tried using promises but "Enter at least one video in the collection first" is already getting rendered when the page is loading. How can I achieve it?

```
 const [display, setdisplay] = useState();
  const [userMsg, setuserMsg] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
    displayFunc();
  }, []);

  function displayFunc() {
    new Promise(function (myResolve) {
      myResolve(
        setTimeout(() => {
          setuserMsg(false);
        }, 2000)
      );
    }).then(() => {
      if (videoIds.length === 0) {
        setdisplay(false);
      } else {
        fetchFunc();
        setTimeout(() => {
          setdisplay(true);
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  }

      {userMsg && <Loading />}
      {display ? (
        <ExploreCard videoArray={videoArray} explVidFunc={explVidFunc} />
      ) : (
        <h1>Enter at least one video in collection first</h1>
      )}
```

Comment: Why does `userMsg === true` mean that the loader is displayed? This name doesn't make sense

Comment: @Konrad iam sorry , i know naming is bad, so userMsg is responsible solely for displaying loading and display toggle between rendering <ExploreCard/> and displaying a heading, so if videoIds.length === 0 then display the heading otherwise render  <ExploreCard/>

Answer (score 0):

```
export const View = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const fetch = async () => {
    // fetch logic here
    setVideos(); // put response or data here
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    /*
      I don't believe the timeout is necessary, but if you want to
      delay the fetch function, you can do something like the following.
      setTimeout(() => fetch(), 3000); 
    */

    fetch();
  }, [videos]);

  return (
    <>
      {!!videos.length && <Loading />}
      {!videos.length ? (
        <ExploreCard
          {/* explVidFunc={explVidFunc */}
          videoArray={videoArray}
        />
      ) : (
        <h1>Enter at least one video in collection first</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
}:
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([])

const fetchVideos = async () => {
    try{
      // call api to fetch videos
      const res = callApi()
      setLoading(false)
      // change according to you response
      setVideos(res.data)
     
    } catch{
       setLoading(false)
}
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchVideos()
},[])
```

Now, you can check for loading . If its true, show Loader else, check for videos. If its length is zero show some component else show different component.

Comment: Catch block only works when request faces an error, you could add finally block after catch it will be it.